# How to get offset values of all files (or given filename) in a zipfile using python?

Tags: python, zip

I really don't know the complexity or the way to go forward. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.header_offset Will it work?

Comment: @bakatrouble: Thanks for the reply. Even I stumbled upon this. But Couldn't find relevant xamples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ZipFile` class contains all what you need:

```
zf = ZipFile(...)

# for all files
for zinfo in zf.infolist():
    print(f'{zinfo.filename}: offset {zinfo.header_offset}')

# for specific file
zinfo = zf.getinfo(filename)
print(f'{zinfo.filename}: offset {zinfo.header_offset}')
```

Comment: If you need the offset of the data of an uncompressed member, it's `zinfo.header_offset + len(zinfo.FileHeader())` (and the data has `zinfo.file_size` bytes).